# A unique solution to $\log_2\prod_{a=1}^{a=C} (3+1/{M_a} ) \in \mathbb{Z}, C \in \mathbb{Z}, M_a \rm{~is~odd}, M_i \ne M_j$

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, logarithms

$$\log_2\prod_{a=1}^{a=C} \left (3 + \frac{1}{M_a} \right) \in \mathbb{Z}, \qquad C \in \mathbb{Z}, \qquad M_a \rm{~is~odd}, \qquad M_i \ne M_j$$

I've been playing with this equation and I'm fairly confident the only solution to this is: $C=1, M_a=1$

Can it be proven this solution is unique? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: $C, M_1,\ldots,M_c$ are positive integers?

Comment: $C$ is an integer, $M_1, \ldots, M_C$ are odd numbers

Comment: The set $C=-1$, so the empty product is usually defined to be $1$, and the log is integer.

Comment: Certainly you have no chance to prove it without proving the absence of cycles in the Collatz conjecture (any such cycle would give you a counterexample) However, it looks like you still have a decent chance to refute it because you can split the number to cancel into several factors at each step, which gives you some extra leeway.

Comment: Trying to solve the Collatz conjecture is where this has come from.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Sorry, C is greater than 1. I assumed that was a given as I've never seen "backwards" summations.

Comment: @fedja It is also possible to formulate a question similar to this which sets up a refute for the infinite sequence.